# Why can't call this function assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a JS code like it:

```js
const supportedRegions = ['usa', 'brazil']

const isSupportedRegion = region => supportedRegions.includes(region)

isSupportedRegion('brazil') // true
```

And it works fine. But if I wrote something like, returns an unexpected error:

```js
const supportedRegions = ['usa', 'brazil']

const isSupportedRegion = supportedRegions.includes

isSupportedRegion('brazil') // error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at includes (<anonymous>) at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Why it is saying that can't convert from `undefined` or `null`?? The variable `isSupportedRegion` is a function!

```js
typeof isSupportedRegion // "function"
isSupportedRegion // ƒ includes() { [native code] }
```

Someone could explain what is happens, please?

Comment: `const isSupportedRegion = supportedRegions.includes` means it loses the `this` context of `supportedRegions` and all you're left with is `Array.prototype.includes`, use `.bind` or `() => supportedRegions.includes(region)`